# MySQL start failed

Tags: mysql, apache

When I start MySQL (/etc/init.d/mysql start) I'll get this error:

> Starting service MySQL warning: /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock didn't
>   appear within 30 seconds chmod: cannot access
>   `/var/run/mysql/mysqld.pid': No such file or directory

I've already stopped the running MySQL Server (/etc/init.d/mysql stop)

Comment: Are you running it as root?

Comment: need chmod a+x maybe

Comment: see this https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/28015/icehouse-mysql-will-not-start/

Comment: the needed files in /var/run/mysql/ doesn't exist..

Comment: If you are not running as root try with sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start

Alternative can you give the result of the following command [2-3 lines below and above including "chmod: cannot access  `/var/run/mysql/mysqld.pid': No such file or directory']:
bash -x /etc/init.d/mysql start

Comment: Maybe add "skip-networking" to my.cnf as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238626/mysql-can%C2%B4t-start-server-debian-wheezy/28440317#28440317.